# custom image layout border in dialog

Tags: android

In my app I have this situation: I open dialog and set the content view like this:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
```

dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/patientsbg"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

And the result is this:

[image]

I want to have dialog exactly with my image and with no borders and spaces.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set your dialog background transparent as below:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
 dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

**OR**

Try to apply the theme to your dialog to remove the border of your dialog as below:

Create a style in your `res/style` and write below code in it.

```
<style name="Dialog_No_Border">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">#00000000</item>
</style>
```

And set the above style in your dialog as below:

```
 dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.Dialog_No_Border);
```